# old version fortran do loop manova code

Tags: c++, fortran

I'm attempting to replicate multivariate statistical code from  1971 publication. Fortran version not specified. I'm porting int to C++ and don't understand the following snippet;
From Cooley and Lohnes - Multivariate Data Analysis

```
DO 12 NS = 1, NG
READ(5, TIT)        (V(J),  J = 1, M)
DO 12   J = 1, M
U(J) =  U(J) + V(J)
T(J) =  T(J) + V(J)
DO 12   K = 1, M
A(J, K) = A(J,K) + V(J) * V(K)
```

12  C(J, K) = C(J,K) + V(J) * V(K)

Specifically, I don't understand how V(J) gets populated in the second line. Any help from a Fortran guru will be greatly appreciated. BTW TIT is an array that contains a project description so I don't get why it's being read here.

Comment: Why don't you learn Fortran basics when you port code from Fortran? This was treated here many times.

Comment: "TIT is an array"  That makes no sense. You should actually show that declaration if you still need help.

Comment: DIMENSION TIT(16), A(50,50, B(50,50) C(50,50)

Comment: `TIT` is not being read, it is a format description. Please see the link and *do read the answers there*, it is all described there in great detail. Please do read it. It is the purpose of marking the duplicates, that you can read those answers people already wrote about the topic. `TIT` should be a character string, but I can imagine a character array or integer Hollerith array would also work.

Comment: If you provide more detail and [edit] the question and actually ask about the details, the question *might* be eligible for re-opening, but so far it is just a clear duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The `V(J), J=1,M` is basically an implicit loop,  so it's roughly equivalent to something like

```
for (i=1; i <= m; i++)
    infile >> v[i];
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I just couldn't figure out what format TIT referred to. This is an old card reader program so i'm guessing that format is on a card I can't see. It looks like the data retrieved is M variables from line X. These data now reside in a linked list in the c++ version.